# How to vote for both answers and question using the Answers module?

Tags: rating, 7

I am using [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers) module. In that only for nodes of type ***Question*** I can add vote up/down field.

But I wonder how I can add a voting feature for the nodes of type ***Answer***?

Answer (score 2):

Instead use [Question/Answer](https://drupal.org/project/question_answer) module, it have the vote system for both question and answer

> It adds a question/answer section for website. Different from other
>   modules, it uses only one node type for question, and the core
>   comment.module for answer. This allow reutilisation of CCK, Views..

or

You can try [Vote Up/Down](https://drupal.org/project/vote_up_down) module

> Allows votes on some drupal entities and provides the base for
>   implementing votes on other entities

or take a look at [Rate](https://drupal.org/project/rate) module

> This module provides flexible voting widgets for nodes and comments.
>   Multiple ratings on the same node (i.e. for "comfort", "location",
>   "services" etc.)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the most recent 7.x.-4.x version of the [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers) module, then all that should be needed is to enable the "Answers Voting" submodule (which of course requires its dependencies to be enabled also).

To see it at work, head over to [an online example from its demo site](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/50) (this site has read only access for anonymous users though). Be aware that this demo version is a further enhanced version of the most recent dev release (eg the views have been enhanced) which will be pushed to D.O shortly), though there are no differences for the Answers Voting submodule as compared to what's available on D.O.

Disclosure: I'lm a co-maintainer of this module.